# Dynamically assigning function implementation in Python

Tags: python, anonymous-function, anonymous-methods, callable

I want to assign a function implementation dynamically.

Let's start with the following:

```
class Doer(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Bob"

    def doSomething(self):
        print "%s got it done" % self.name

def doItBetter(self):
    print "Done better"
```

In other languages we would make doItBetter an anonymous function and assign it to the object. But no support for anonymous functions in Python. Instead, we'll try making a callable class instance, and assign that to the class:

```
class Doer(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Bob"

class DoItBetter(object):

    def __call__(self):
        print "%s got it done better" % self.name

Doer.doSomething = DoItBetter()
doer = Doer()
doer.doSomething()
```

That gives me this:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   Line 13, in 
>       doer.doSomething()   Line 9, in **call**
>       print "%s got it done better" % self.name AttributeError: 'DoItBetter' object has no attribute 'name'

Finally, I tried assigning the callable to the object instance as an attribute and calling it:

```
class Doer(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Bob"

class DoItBetter(object):

    def __call__(self):
        print "%s got it done better" % self.name


doer = Doer()
doer.doSomething = DoItBetter()
doer.doSomething()
```

This DOES work as long as I don't reference self in DoItBetter, but when I do it gives me an name error on `self.name` because it's referencing the callable's `self`, not the owning class `self`.

So I'm looking for a pythonic way to assign an anonymous function to a class function or instance method, where the method call can reference the object's `self`.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the very first approach that you rejected. Why are you making it so complex?

Comment: Your error is really odd - are you trying to run a Python script with a ruby interpreter? (Your file is called `prog.rb`, `.py` is the Python file extension). The error definitely isn't from Python - `self` isn't a keyword in Python.

Comment: My mistake- ran it on an online codepad with ruby settings- fixed

Comment: @David- you're right- I was making it way too complicated

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Your first approach was OK, you just have to assign the function to the class:

```
class Doer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Bob"

    def doSomething(self):
        print "%s got it done" % self.name

def doItBetter(self):
    print "%s got it done better" % self.name

Doer.doSomething = doItBetter
```

Anonymous functions have nothing to do with this (by the way, Python supports simple anonymous functions consisting of single expressions, see `lambda`).

Comment: +1 being anonymous doesn't matter here - all that matters is you can assign a function.

Answer (score 39):

yak's answer works great if you want to change something for every instance of a class.

If you want to change the method only for a particular *instance* of the object, and not for the entire class, you'd need to use the `MethodType` type constructor to create a bound method:

```
from types import MethodType

doer.doSomething = MethodType(doItBetter, doer)
```

Comment: At least in Python 3, it should be `doer.doSomething = MethodType(doItBetter, doer)` .   
A good explanation of the different cases for methods and functions is given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/972/adding-a-method-to-an-existing-object-instance

Comment: @yanlend this question was asked for Python 2.