# Assigning __str__ method in __init__ not working as expected in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object, types

I tried to conditionally create the

```
__str__
```

method in a python class, as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374527/dynamically-assigning-function-implementation-in-python#10374569) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972/adding-a-method-to-an-existing-object-instance) and I understand that is is not recommended to do this. But for my understanding, doing:

```
from types import MethodType

def str_fcn(self):
    return self.a

class A(object):
    def __init__(self, a=None):
        if a is not None:
            self.a = a
            self.__str__ = MethodType(str_fcn, self)
            self.test = MethodType(str_fcn, self)

a = A(a="name")

print(a)
print(a.test())
```

Does not seem to work for magic methods. The last print call at the end prints "name" as I expect, but the first uses the default string representation. Why?

Comment: Because magic methods are never looked up on the instance, see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-lookup

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I am wondering if one can use `self` as the argument of a function outside the class like the OP did in his code for `def str_fcn(self):`?

Comment: @Bazingaa: absolutely. `self` is not a reserved name, it's just a convention.